# Display time on X Axis of Digital Waveform Graph

Tags: labview

I'd like to know is it ever possible to show time (doesn't matter relative or absolute) on X Axis of Digital Waveform Graph, not Waveform Graph. Now it shows the number of samples at specific points. I'm generating an 8-channel signal with NI Card and as of right now I don't have access to it, so I wouldn't be able to check the solution rapidly.

I've [read this](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvconcepts/types_of_graphs_and_charts/#Digital_Waveform_Graphs) topic from NI, but didn't get the answer for my question.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user interface: right-click on the graph -> properties -> display format -> Time (x-axis). You can set most of the options shown below programmatically using a property node, but not the very useful "custom" format (arbitrary sprintf expression) exposed with the "advanced editing mode".

[image: Object Properties:Digital Waveform Graph]

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert. I'll try this method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help, but I found [this](https://vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fknowledge.ni.com%2FKnowledgeArticleDetails%3Fid%3DkA00Z000000P9QESA0%26l%3Dru-RU&el=snippet) article, which worked. I presume that your option is applicable for version of LabView greater than 8.2.1.